# FPDF Merge PDFs - How to fix error “erreur dans xref”?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using fpdf_merge script to combined pdfs into one.

Source: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script94.php

The example code works fine.

```
    <?php 
    require('fpdf_merge.php');

    $merge = new FPDF_Merge();
    $merge->add('doc1.pdf');
    $merge->add('doc2.pdf');
    $merge->output();
    ?>
```

But it throws error “erreur dans xref” when I merge PDFS with images. Let me know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when you try to merge PDF with compression.

Doing it with this class only PDF with version 1.4 or previous can be merge since compression was not supported on that versions.

With newer PDF versions you can configure the compression settings if you have a PDF software that support that kind of changes.